# How to associate OpenID to an old StackOverflow account?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts

I had a SO account (named hamen).  I'd like to associate an OpenID to that account.  When I try to login with OpenID it simply creates a new account.  The name is still hamen because OpenID provides it, but it's a brand-new account.  I could migrate to this new SO account, but I cannot set my email address because:

> Oops! There was a problem updating
>   your profile:
>
> ```
> * Email - is already registered
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

You might want to email team@stackoverflow.com and see if they can't help you get your accounts merged successfully.