# Lost my actual Stack Overflow ID

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, user-accounts

I lost my old Stack Overflow ID with the new OpenID changes. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 5):

We can almost certainly recover this relatively easily, but you'll need to give us somewhere to start - what was your account called, for example? "here" (meta), or a moderator flag on SO may be quicker than the e-mail approach (heck, I'm here now...). We'll also need to confirm that it is your account. Then we can just merge with your new SO account.

If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92076/somasekhar) is your account, then you just need to use the subdomain. I've e-mailed your openid to your listed e-mail address (from the old account).

Update: confirmed via e-mail discussion and merged.

Answer (score 4):

Best write a mail to `team@stackoverflow.com` with information.

Comment: Sigh. That isn't the only (or perhaps even the best) option; the ♦ moderators can deal with user account enquiries...

Comment: Is this new? I was under the impression that also ♦ moderators referred these kind of problems usually to team@so (like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7423/lost-openid-account/15026#15026 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22568/recover-a-deleted-account/22577#22577 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3948/how-do-i-consolidate-my-stackoverflow-accounts/3952#3952 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/how-to-associate-openid-to-an-old-stackoverflow-account/13925#13925...). Probably it's a case by case question who can help.

Comment: Not especially. At least one of those relates to a *deleted* account, which is very different. But I'm perfectly willing to handle merge requests from MSO, as long as we can confirm identity without disclosing priveleged info in the public arena.